# Is it possible to use terraform with IBM classic infrastructure?

Tags: ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

I'm trying to create a classic virtual server using terraform by following below two articles but I'm getting an error.

**Articles**

1. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ibm-cloud-provider-for-terraform?topic=ibm-cloud-provider-for-terraform-getting-started
2. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ibm-cloud-provider-for-terraform?topic=ibm-cloud-provider-for-terraform-sample_infrastructure_config

**Error**

**Error: Error ordering virtual guest: Error generating order template: SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Access Denied.  (HTTP 401)**

**provider.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    ibm = {
      source = "IBM-Cloud/ibm"
      version = "1.21.2"
    }
  }
}

variable "ibmcloud_api_key" {}
variable "iaas_classic_username" {}
variable "iaas_classic_api_key" {}

provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key   = var.ibmcloud_api_key
  region             = "sng01"
  iaas_classic_username = var.iaas_classic_username
  iaas_classic_api_key  = var.iaas_classic_api_key
}
```

**classic-vsi.tf**

```
resource "ibm_compute_vm_instance" "vm1" {
hostname             = "vm1"
domain               = "testing.com"
os_reference_code    = "DEBIAN_8_64"
datacenter           = "sng01"
network_speed        = 10
hourly_billing       = true
private_network_only = false
cores                = 1
memory               = 1024
disks                = [25]
local_disk           = false
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
ibmcloud_api_key = ""
iaas_classic_username = "emailID"
iaas_classic_api_key = ""
```

for **iaas_classic_api_key** I followed this [article](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-classic_keys)

for **ibmcloud_api_key** I followed this [article](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-userapikey#create_user_key)

Is it possible to use terraform OR it is deprecated in favor of VPC2 Infrastructure?

Please help.

**UPDATE**

fixed the `401` error by replacing the value of `iaas_classic_username` from email-ID to IBM account six-digit unique ID. check the User-name by following the below article.

Reference article: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-vpnpassword

Now I'm getting the below error.

**Error: Error ordering virtual guest: SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Unavailable: Debian GNU/Linux 8.x jessie/Stable - Minimal Install (64 bit) is not available as of 09/12/2020 (Item #(6195). (HTTP 500)**

Comment: Add details like your TF file. How did you authenticate? Access denied likely means that your configuration is wrong

Comment: @data_henrik I have added all the files I'm using. Please help.

Comment: And you get that error during "tf plan"? What commands have you used?

Comment: I would recommend that you provision a resource through the console first, then try to read it using TF. If that works in your environment, use TF to provision it.

Comment: yes @data_henrik error is comming when I'm running `terraform plan` command. 

Sure I'll try it using console first.

Comment: hello @data_henrik It seems that the value of `iaas_classic_username` isn't the email-ID. Now I'm using six digits unique ID(account-ID) in username and I'm not getting `401` error anymore but there are still some error like **`Error: Error ordering virtual guest: SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Unavailable: Debian GNU/Linux 8.x jessie/Stable - Minimal Install (64 bit) is not available as of 09/12/2020 (Item #(6195). (HTTP 500)`**. Can you please help?

Comment: Use a different image name. Check what is available.

Comment: It seems that `DEBIAN_8_64` is deprecated and now the minimum version is `DEBIAN_9_64`. it's working fine after updating it to `DEBIAN_9_64`. Thanks a  lot @data_henrik for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the OS image you are trying to order is no longer available. You will need to use Debian 9 or 10.

```
⇒  slcli vs create-options | grep -i 'Debian 9'
Debian 9.0.0-64 LAMP for VSI                                            OS_DEBIAN_9_X_STRETCH_LAMP_64_BIT                       DEBIAN_9_64
Debian 9.0.0-64 Minimal for VSI                                         OS_DEBIAN_9_X_STRETCH_MINIMAL_64_BIT                    DEBIAN_9_64

⇒  slcli vs create-options | grep -i 'Debian 10'
Debian 10.0.0-64 Minimal for VSI                                        OS_DEBIAN_10_X_BUSTER_MINIMAL_64_BIT_VSI                DEBIAN_10_64
```

If you had a specific need to use Jessie, you can use your own OS with a classic VSI. This [guide](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/image-templates?topic=image-templates-preparing-and-importing-images) outlines the process preparing a custom image for import.

On another note, you will want to use [flavor_key_name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/compute_vm_instance#flavor_key_name) in place of setting core and memory values directly. The core/memory combo is still supported by the Classic API but does not support new features like suspended billing and may be deprecated in the future.